# Is the delta operator commutative in terms of multiplication

Tags: calculus

It's a rather simple question that for some reason I can't seem to wrap my head around but it true that $\nabla v \nabla u = \nabla u \nabla v$?

Comment: The $\nabla$ operator operated here, over scalars produce vectors $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$. So you have to be specific. If the product were *dot* it is commutative, if it were *cross*, it is anti-commutative.

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure but is performing $(\nabla u)^{2}$ a dot product operation? If so then yes, otherwise no